# I accidently disabled virtualbox host-only network for Genymotion

Tags: networking, virtualbox, genymotion

I accidentally disabled my virtualbox host-only network in Network and sharing folder and it disappeared, and now I cannot do anything in Genymotion due to a network error. How do I find the network to enable it or get Genymotion to work again?

Answer (score 0):

Genymobile soft is supposed to recreate the apropriate network on the fly when needed.
Make sure you use the last version and it should be fine.